# solving pipelining data hazards using stalls

Tags: computer-architecture

I have a question about fixing data hazards in a pipelined datapath using stalls. I have read slightly varying things on this. Some lectures I have found put the instruction decode (ID) in the same step as the write back and some put it in the next step. From what ive read, in the first example the write can be done in the first half of the step and the ID in the second half. If this is possible why is the second example needed, or are there specific occasions where both need to be used.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the precise definitions of the various stages (all all processors have their own, often using similar names for more or less subtly different definitions) and what circuitry is also available (such as forwarding paths).

Putting ID at the same time as WB seems to assume the existence of a forwarding path while putting ID after WB completed seems to assume that so such path exists.

Comment: so in my case i have a question that is asking for the calculation of a programs execution time, using stalls where needed. there is no other information regarding forwarding paths etc. which one should be used ?

Comment: I've less clues than you about your teacher's intentions. I just can say that there are multiple reasonable answers and that explains why your sources differ. Depending on the teacher, what is wanted may be a discussion of why there are multiple answers possible, a verbatim of what has been said during the lessons or something in between... And the ambiguity may be a limitation in his preparation, just an oversight or even a teaching tool: in practice, there is rarely clear cut answers, especially in engineering which can be considered as the art of trade-off involving technical aspects.

Comment: thanks for your answer. unfortunately this is for an entrance exam and therefore dont have contact nor even knowledge of who wrote the question. I guess ill just try to ask around.

Comment: For an entrance exam, I'd go with the discussion of why multiple answers are possible or, -- if time is too short -- take one choice but state my assumptions clearly.